# pycket error when starting tornado application - syntax

Tags: tornado

Using pycket,

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
       tornado.web.url(r'/(?P<uuid>.+)', ArticlePage),tornado.web.url(r'/signup', SignUpHandler),tornado.web.url(r'/login', LoginHandler) ,tornado.web.url(r'/makeacc', AccountCreationHandler),tornado.web.url(r'/logout', LogoutHandler) 
    ],**{
'pycket': {
    'engine': 'redis',
    'storage': {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 6379,
        'db_sessions': 10,
        'db_notifications': 11,
        'max_connections': 2 ** 31,
    },
    'cookies': {
        'expires_days': 120,
    },
})
```

I try to just make the app, exactly the same way that is done on the main page under examples for redis https://github.com/diogobaeder/pycket.

and I get this error

```
  File "server.py", line 122
    })
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Nothing looks wrong to me. Not sure what the issue is because I used the starting code exactly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing one closing brace:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    tornado.web.url(r'/(?P<uuid>.+)', ArticlePage),tornado.web.url(r'/signup', SignUpHandler),tornado.web.url(r'/login', LoginHandler) ,tornado.web.url(r'/makeacc', AccountCreationHandler),tornado.web.url(r'/logout', LogoutHandler)
],**{
'pycket': {
    'engine': 'redis',
    'storage': {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 6379,
        'db_sessions': 10,
        'db_notifications': 11,
        'max_connections': 2 ** 31,
    },
    'cookies': {
        'expires_days': 120,
    },
}})
```

Editors specialized for writing code, like Emacs, PyCharm, Komodo, Sublime, or any number of other code editors and IDEs, have features to make it obvious when you mismatch braces, parentheses, or brackets.

Comment: Thank you, they are actually missing it in the example, weird -basically for everyone else, example is missing a }, hard to see. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you make a pull request to pycket to benefit future users. And will you mark my answer "accepted" here, please?